# Windows 10 - no Startup folder in Task Manager

Tags: windows, boot, task-manager

I am trying to disable several application from auto starting after restarting computer.

However - can not see `Startup` folder in `Task Manager`:

[image]

Where to find it / how to enable it?

Comment: Are you an Administrator on the local machine?  If you are connected to a domain, that makes a difference, so confirm if that is the case.  Outside of that [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) should be used.  Please note do not disable anything you are not sure of.  I am going on under the assumption the startup tab is supposed to be missing since you are not an Administrator.  So don't run Autoruns without permission.

Answer (score 4):

- Your screenshot shows the 'Classic' (Windows 7) Task Manager, which you probably [installed from WinAero](https://winaero.com/blog/get-classic-old-task-manager-in-windows-10/). Uninstall it to get the real Windows 10 Task Manager app back.
- As of Windows 10.1803, the same feature can be found in the *Settings* app, under *Apps → Startup*. Eventually it might be removed from Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

A better tool is
[autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

With this tool you can disable and enable startups with a click and refine
the display by filter and display either all the startups or separate them by section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note, too, that in addition to autoruns (which I also recommend), you can view the contents of the Startup folder itself (which is not available from the Windows 10 menu) in the following ways:

- Issue the command `shell:startup`.
- Navigate to `C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

---

An application that starts with Windows, however, may well not be in this folder—as many other things can cause an application to start automatically.